# how to add a "console" like window to a GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have created a GUI. It has several buttons. i would like to add a console like object underneath them in which i would be able to write messages so the user would see them. 
what element/object/class should i use? i want it to be able to present messages in different lines.
here is my code for creating the GUI:

```
public ssGUI() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    bRunNoAdj = new JButton("Run no adjustment");
    bRunNoAdj.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    bRunNoAdj.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING);
    bRunNoAdj.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    bRunNoAdj.addActionListener(this);
    bRunNoAdj.setEnabled(false);
    bRunNoAdj.setBackground(Color.white);

    bRunAdj = new JButton("Run adjustment");
    bRunAdj.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    bRunAdj.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING);
    bRunAdj.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    bRunAdj.addActionListener(this);
    bRunAdj.setEnabled(false);
    bRunAdj.setBackground(Color.white);

    bConnect = new JButton("Connect");
    bConnect.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    bConnect.addActionListener(this);
    bConnect.setEnabled(true);
    bConnect.setBackground(Color.white);

    bDisconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
    bDisconnect.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    bDisconnect.addActionListener(this);
    bDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
    bDisconnect.setBackground(Color.white);

    bStationary = new JButton("Show Stationary");
    bStationary.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    bStationary.addActionListener(this);
    bStationary.setEnabled(false);
    bStationary.setBackground(Color.white);

    bMoving = new JButton("Show Moving");
    bMoving.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    bMoving.addActionListener(this);
    bMoving.setEnabled(false);
    bMoving.setBackground(Color.white);

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.add(bConnect);
    topPanel.add(bDisconnect);
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    centerPanel.add(bRunNoAdj);
    centerPanel.add(bRunAdj);
    add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    bottomPanel.add(bStationary);
    bottomPanel.add(bMoving);
    add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You could just use a `JTextArea` and `setEditable(false)` on it.

Comment: why should i set it false?

Comment: @DanyLavrov is you do not set it to false then the user will be able to delete or alter the messages you've added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to use a JTextArea.

You would ofcourse prevent the user from editing the area, this can be done like this:

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
area.setEditable(false);
```

And if you want the user to be able to scroll the area you can add it to a JScrollPane like this:

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scrollableArea = new JScrollPane(area);
```

And lastly you can add a line to the area by doing:

```
area.setText(area.getText() + "\n" + newLine);
```

Or preferably:

```
area.append("\n" + newLine);
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks. one last thing. on the first load all the components in the main frame are squeezed together. why is this happening? i am trying to use the `setSize()` method but it doesnt help.

Comment: How do you mean squeezed together? By the way if you are using a layout manager then `setSize()` is ignored as it is usually calculated by the layoutmanager, `setPreferredSize()` is used by some layout managers though.

Comment: some of the buttons are on top of each other. It is not a big deal. for example the scroll panel has only one line at the first loading, can i make it 3 line wide for example from the start?

Comment: Yes you can. Instead of using the standard JTextArea constructor you can also use this constructor: `new JTextArea(rows, cols)` (where rows and cols are both integers`. This way you can create the JTextArea with an initial number of rows and columns. I hope this helps :)

Comment: great. now last question ( i promise) it seems like the `bottompanel` is overlaying the `centerpanel`. i am using the border layout. why is this happening?

Comment: That is weird because if the two were overlaying it would mean that BorderLayout isn't doing such a good job. (And I've never seen BorderLayout failing). Are you sure that it's not just some of the panel content being cut off?

Comment: Don't sure what do you mean by "cut off". the content of the center panel is overlaid by the content of the bottom one, but after i re-size the main frame manually every thing is fine.

Comment: That is indeed a little weird, maybe you can just open the main frame with a bigger size? Would that be acceptable or does it have to work straight from the start?

Comment: Also use append over setText, apart from been easier, it's more efficient

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`JTextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html).  Call `text_area.setEditable(false);` on it to make it read-only.

Comment: why should it be false?

Comment: Your "console" is an output only window; `setEditable(false)` makes the control read-only.  The user should not be able to change messages your program has displayed.  Your program, of course, is able to add more lines to it, or make any other changes at will.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is JTextArea or JTextField